# Ubuntu MPIO at Boot

Tags: server

I am trying to get Ubuntu Server 16.04 or 18.04 to install on IBM POWER PPC LE system.

Primary issue is that installation is via NPV virtual adapters to SAN boot lun (will use this to setup template for mass VM deployments).  But issue comes when OS install scans disk.  The single boot volume shows 8 times (aka no MPIO).

Others noted issue: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=f2042cc2-c438-4dc3-9509-c5c670eb0a97 and https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/MultipathSupport

**Questions:**

1. Is there a distro level fix where MPIO can be activated at boot (grub option)?
2. Is there a way to get to a secondary console WITHOUT control characters (ex: <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f2</kbd>) as this does not work over SOL (Serial Over LAN) or Java console redirect of SOL.

I really can't believe I am the first to hit this issue with Ubuntu Server... but after days of trying OEM support, trying to track this down myself..

**Update:** Here is link to my edit of Install Kernel at boot... not sure if it worked... devices still list as /dev/sd   vs mpath

[image]

Comment: Regarding 1: your 2nd link says you need a patched grub to get MPIO to work.  2. Unlikely.

Comment: I obviously do not want to have to unpack ubuntu installer and re-package to fix it..    I tried to simply pass kernel parameters to the Ubuntu Installer kernel but not sure if it took... as I have no way to get to alternate console to poke around.  <forum not smart enough to embed image in response.. will post in parent thread>